# How to make the image not to crop?

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

How do I make my background image in the body not to crop when it resizes the window? The site it responsive and the image dosen't resize it juts crops off bits of it. I tried using position:fixed but it didn't work. What code do you need to help me?

This it the code for that wrapper:

```
.body-wrapper {
    background-image: url('http://promegaekonomi.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/82.png') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100% auto;
}
```

Comment: background-size: cover ?

Comment: @Evgeniy `cover` will crop the image, it should be `contain` http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/7y4sv21d/1/

Comment: @web-tiki, both rules does not crop image, they scale it. `cover` to the smallest size, `contain` to the largest that both width and its height can cover the background area. Anyway its also a correct approach and depends of result user expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/yg17acL0/

Try to use the img tag inside the div.

```
.responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS: `background-size:contain`

Working [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/unsupzy9/2/)

(Updated)

Comment: I tried this but it dident work. I copy pasted the code but dident work. What did i do wrong?